# Synchronizing Development and production environments in Drupal

Tags: drupal, migration, drupal-modules, development-environment, production-environment

Synchronizing my Drupal dev and prod environments is turning out to be a bigger brain scratcher than I would have so far imagined.

There does not seem to exist one consistent way for developers to sync their work without the hassle of manually keeping track of what has been uploaded and what has not been uploaded with a lot of developers having found their own way around it.

For instance, if I have a module that I decided to disable and uninstall on my local environment then I ought to have a way to mitigate this to my production website without me off course having to recreate the same step on my production environment. Pushing changes like I would usually with another framework does not make a lot of sense to me since Drupals internal mechanism works differently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give Backup and Migrate a shot. Not the perfect solution but it's the best I've found. http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

Comment: backup and migrate seems like a solution for database changes, I am more concerned about syncing the site seamlessly

Comment: also, my prod site has content on it that the dev site does not, this implies further deep syncing between the two so that each of the sites remain up to date? maybe having the same database is a solution?

Comment: Do you have the option of just installing git between your live server and your local server? Seems like that might be a good option. [Here is a good tutorial for doing so](http://kovshenin.com/2011/01/howto-remote-shared-git-repository-3028/)

Comment: yes I plan on doing so as well. However, having GIT in the middle of my live and local server does not necessarily solve the problem of deciding what needs to be pushed live seamlessly. GIT is a good solution to version controlling, if I am not mistaken?  Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like what [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) was created for.

Answer (score 0):

Found "Features" module from a guy's blog:
http://codekarate.com/blog/top-ten-best-drupal-7-contrib-modules

Check the second paragraph in "Best Drupal 7 Module #8" section.

I have not yet tried it, but found these links while searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use migraine : http://www.slideshare.net/drupalindia/migraine-drupal-syncing-your-staging-and-live-sites-presentation

Works like a charm for me !